# Error in passing string

Tags: .net, visual-studio, c++-cli

I have a simple question and may is an elementary.

I am passing a `string` via a float `function` and I have the following error

```
float formel(float K, float N, float H1, float H2, float L, float G, String^ Kop)
{
   float temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5, temp6;
    temp1 = L*(1.86f + G);
    temp2 = 0.76f*temp1*(H2 - H1);
    temp3 = 0.325f*K*(0.81f - H1);
    temp4 = N*(temp2 + temp3);
    temp5 = 0.042f*temp4;
    if (Kop == "stand")
    {
        temp6 = temp5 * 0.047f*K;
    }
    else
    {
        temp6 = temp5;
    }
    return temp6;
}
```

and the error

> error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'String'

Comment: Crystal ball says that you are missing a `using namespace System;` directive.  Use `System::String` instead.  Or use `const char*`, seems a bit more appropriate for this code.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks a lot. That solved my problem. `System::String ^ Kop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Hans Passant for the hint. The answer is as:

```
float formel(float K, float N, float H1, float H2, float L, float G, System::String ^ Kop)
{
   float temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5, temp6;
    temp1 = L*(1.86f + G);
    temp2 = 0.76f*temp1*(H2 - H1);
    temp3 = 0.325f*K*(0.81f - H1);
    temp4 = N*(temp2 + temp3);
    temp5 = 0.042f*temp4;
    if (Kop == "stand")
    {
        temp6 = temp5 * 0.047f*K;
    }
    else
    {
        temp6 = temp5;
    }
    return temp6;
}
```